# What's a novel with steampunk cyborgs and an armless king?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I picked up this book several years ago in a library I wasn't a member of and forgot to look for it later. Here are a few details I recall:

- It's third person, with at least two POV characters.
- One of the POV characters is at one point engaged at a high-class brothel, although she escapes before she meets her first client.
- There's a drug called leaff that is used to prolong life and maintain a youthful physical state.
- The king of the realm is a figurehead that literally has no arms. The young prince does have arms, but his minders threaten to cut them off early when he misbehaves.
- There's some sort of revolutionary group that amasses supporters by promising them better lives and then turns them into cyborgs.
- It's steampunk, so the setting's overall feel is pre-modern.

Any guesses?

Comment: Do you have an idea of when it was published?

Comment: All I can remember is that it was out in paperback before 2014.

Comment: Is the drug called "leaff" with two f's or is that a spelling mistake?

Comment: To my recollection, it's "leaff" with two f's, but it could be some other aberrant variation on "leaf."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [*The Court of the Air*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765360225)

This is a steampunk novel published in 2009, by Stephen Hunt. It fits most of the facts in the question.

There are at least two point-of-view characters, as mentioned in the question: the prince, and Molly, who was employed at a brothel.

The King literally has no arms:

> Molly nodded. The King’s robes had been subtly tailored to accentuate
> the fact that both of his arms had been surgically removed, and in
> time the young prince would no doubt be dragged bawling to the
> bone-cutter’s table by his Special Guard jailers.
>
> It had been ever thus, since Isambard Kirkhill strode across the land
> in a sea of blood and pistol smoke to assert parliament’s right of
> supremacy at the head of the new pattern army. No monarch shall ever
> raise his arms against his people again.

The prince is threatened with having his arms removed early:

> Hoggstone rose up and drove a ham-sized fist into the prince’s
> stomach. The boy doubled up on the floor and the First Guardian kicked
> him in the head. ‘As it should be, Your Highness. Now shut up, or
> we’ll take your arms off early, cover them in gold plate and show them
> next to your father’s down in the People’s Hall.’

There is a drug called "leaaf":

> Molly gnawed suspiciously at the square. It was almost tasteless, the
> consistency of wet clay. ‘What is it?’
>
> ‘Leaaf,’ said Justine.